# Newbie to html, why isnt this code working? the Text isnt appearing properply?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Beschreibung der Seite (erscheint in der Titelzeile des Browsers)
    <title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Dieser Text wird im Browserfenster angezeigt.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I dont know what is wrong my Text doesnt appear right where it should be!

Comment: Maybe `</title>` tag not closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close the title-tag

```
<title>Beschreibung der Seite (erscheint in der Titelzeile des Browsers)</title>
```

Try this and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The close tag of `<title>` is wrong.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Beschreibung der Seite (erscheint in der Titelzeile des Browsers)
    </title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Dieser Text wird im Browserfenster angezeigt.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to forget to close the title tag in the `<head>`, remember to close tags, if you change it to `</title>`, it should work!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but as mentioned above you need to close the open tags:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>    
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>
           KBeschreibung der Seite (erscheint in der Titelzeile des Browsers)
        </title>
    </head>
  <body>
    <p>Dieser Text wird im Browserfenster angezeigt.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```